# Operator precedence for multiple parentheses in Java

Tags: java, operators

For example, if `currNode.left` and `currNode.right` were null, I would want the if statement to break before evaluating any further than `currNode.left != null`, but the following if statement throw a null pointer error because it's evaluating the statement in the parentheses first:

```
if (currNode.left != null && currNode.right != null && (currNode.left.val == x && currNode.right.val == y) || (currNode.left.val == y && currNode.right.val == x))
```

where as an extra pair of parentheses at the end gives the desired behavior:

```
if (currNode.left != null && currNode.right != null && ((currNode.left.val == x && currNode.right.val == y) || (currNode.left.val == y && currNode.right.val == x)))
```

I know `()` is evaluated before `&&`, but I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical OR `||` has lower precedence than the logical AND `&&`. So:

```
A && B || C && D
```

is equivalent to:

```
(A && B) || (C && D)
```

whereas what inside the parentheses are evaluated first.

---

Read more about operators in Java:

- [The Java™ Tutorials - Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

---

EDIT:

In your first example:

```
A && B && (C && D) || (E && F)
```

this is evaluated as follows:

```
= A && B && (C && D) || (E && F)
=   R1   && (C && D) || (E && F) 
=   R1   &&    R2    || (E && F)
=   R1   &&    R2    ||    R3
=        R4          ||    R3
=                    R5
```

In your second example:

```
A && B && ((C && D) || (E && F))
```

this is evaluated as follows:

```
= A && B && ((C && D) || (E && F))
=   R1   && ((C && D) || (E && F))
=   R1   && (   R2    || (E && F))
=   R1   && (   R2    ||    R3   )
=   R1   &&           R4
=        R5
```

---

Note that `&&` and `||` are short-circuit operators, which means the right operand will not be evaluated if the result can be inferred from evaluating the left operand.

Comment: But in my case where A && B && (C && D) || (E && F), it's evaluating (C&&D) first, so why wouldn't this also happen when it's A && B && ((C && D) || (E && F))?

Comment: In the first example, `(C && D)` is ANDed with `A && B` first, whereas in the second example, it is ORed with `(E && F)` first.